# How to copy a nodelist?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom, render

I am trying to set up a search feature for a large table that has about 1000 rows. The problem with this is that the rendering eats up performance by a lot. This is because I am iterating through all the rows in the table and setting the style of the ones that do not contain the search query to 'none'.

For some reason, the browser renders all the elements again each time I make a change. I am getting the table data as a nodelist via document.quesrtySelectorAll('tbody tr'). My solution is to copy this to a new object, do the search and style changes on the new object, and then copy it back, causing the browser to only have to re-render the table once.

```
let items = document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');
let itemsArr = [...items];

for (let ele of itemsArr) {
    . . .

    if (!lower_case_table_value.match(lower_case_search_value)) {
        ele.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = 'table-row';
    }
}

let list = document.querySelector('tbody');
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    list.appendChild(itemsArr[i]);
}
```

No matter what I do, though, any changes I make on the new object also makes the changes to the old. I removed the second for loop and it behaves like nothing happened. It is like it is not a copy, but a pointer.

Does anybody know who to copy a nodelist to a new object and make sure they are separate and not pointers to one another?

Comment: Hi, maybe give us a small snippet of your table and how you're trying to copy the documents.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks I just made the edit.

Comment: Isn't it easier to form required features of table on server side? If `tr` contains `td` with no data, then just append smth like `style="display: none"`

Comment: Did you miss `...` in `let itemsArr = [items];`? Otherwise this wouldn't work at all (because `ele === items`).

Comment: @Andreas Yes I do have that, but it is still a pointer, not a new object.

Comment: In the `for...of...` loop you're changing the `display` property of the elements. The second loop and the `.appendChild()` isn't necessary (and only adds more unnecessary work (reflow) for the browser). This would require some testing, but I would guess that cloning the DOM nodes, changing the clones, removing the old nodes and adding the clones, will take more time then just changing the style.

Comment: If you remove the superfluous second `for`/`appendChild` loop, and assuming the elided (`. . .`) code does something simple, this is very performant: https://jsfiddle.net/jrunning/n7c40g6m/

Comment: The fasted way of rerendering was to detach/remove the `tbody` element process all of its `tr` elements as originally intended and then insert the `tbody` again. Thus the OP does not force the browser to rerender every change made to an `tr` within the processing loop. There is no need for cloning any `tr`'s or node-lists since neither does solve the core problem of how to rerender numerous changes to a DOM structure most efficiently / with the lowest possible performance costs.

Answer (score 5):

just tumbled on the same problem today and found that you can copy a DOM node element with the method "node.cloneNode" e.g.:

```
let p = document.getElementById("para1")
let p_prime = p.cloneNode(true)
```

I took the snippet from the MDN documentation that you can find here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode

most probably you already found the solution for this, but anyway, I leave this here for the record.

Answer (score 1):

```
let items = document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');
let itemsArr = [...items];
```

here items is a nodeList
so itemsArray stores also a nodeList
now if you try to iterate over itemsArray
there is only one thing in there which is the nodeList you put in there
insted if you add spread items into itemsArray you'll be storing elements not the entire odeList

Comment: I am doing this, but again, it is not treating it as a separate object. If I make a change to the itemsArr, it also makes the change to items.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get a new Array instead of a chilNode
use `Array.from(nodeToCopy)`
this returns a new Array instead of a child node

Comment: This does not work. It still treats it like a pointer to the original object.

Comment: How do `nodeToCopy` (one DOM node) and `Array.from()` (which creates an array from an iterable) work together? o.O

Comment: if you have a NodeList you want to turn into an array

Comment: 1. TO does this already (with `[...items]`), 2. you're talking about child nodes, and `nodeToCopy` which is still singular which doesn't make much sense in this case

Comment: I understand now

Comment: Insted you can try to use Object.create()